# How to get the total time from a column, using jqgrid?

Tags: datetime, jqgrid

I want to add a Total in the footer. I know how to add the sum of a column. But my question is how to get the sum when the column contains minutes or hours. This is when i have integer or float numbers:

```
 var workedTotal = jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('getCol', 'worked', false, 'sum');

 $(this).jqGrid('footerData','set',
 {name:'TOTAL', worked:workedTotal});
```

As i mention before, I want to know how to get the sum  of the column, when i have datetime formats ? thx

Comment: I have in the column worked this kind of format minutes : "102:32"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getCol` will work only with *numbers* in the column. To make `'sum'` working correctly with the data like `"102:32"` you should add `unformat` function (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter#unformatting)) to the column `'worked'`. The `unformat` function can convert minutes and hours to the number of minutes and to return the result

```js
unformat: function (cell) {
    if (typeof cell !== "string") {
        return 0;
    }
    // now we are sure that we work with strings and can use split
    var arr = cell.split();
    if (arr.length === 2) {
        // standard format of input string like "102:32"
        var h = parseInt(arr[0], 10), m = parseInt(arr[1], 10);
        if (!isNaN(h) && !isNaN(m)) {
            return h * 60 + m;
        }
    }
    return 0; // some exotic input data
}
```

I didn't tested the above code, but I hope if you add `unformat` to definition of the column `'worked'` then

```
var workedTotalMin = jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('getCol', 'worked', false, 'sum');
```

will get you the total number of minutes. You can use [toFixed](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) and [%](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp) to convert the result to the string with minutes or hours before usage of `footerData`.